# Move Quickbook Enterprises Account to online

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

We have a Quick-book Enterprises version, how do I access through API? where do I  find the API key. I have attached the Licence key. Is there a way that we connect enterprises account through API.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> how do I access through API?

Go read the QuickBooks SDK documentation.

> where do I find the API key.

There isn't one. Go read the documentation and at least make an attempt at doing this yourself before posting here.

> Is there a way that we connect enterprises account through API.

Yes.